# slide out nav not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
    }
}
```

```css
body {margin:0;}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav li:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a></li>
</ul>

<div style="padding-left:16px">
  <h2>Responsive Topnav Example</h2>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see how it works.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

In the code when the screen size is less than 600px the home tab stays and the rest should be available through the hamburger icon which should show up at the right corner but it doesn't work. 
What did I do wrong?
What changes should I do to make it work?
Please Help

Answer (score 2):

Though other answers provide a solution using your current code, I would recommend a different approach for quite a few things...

- **Unobtrusive JS is important for a better SoC (Separation of Concerns).** Keep it out of the HTML/global scope with the `addEventListener()` method and, optionally, an IIFE.
- **CSS should take more of a mobile-first approach.**
- **`:hover` should nearly always be accompanied by `:focus`.** Use the tab key to jump from control to control and you'll see why. Not everyone is using a mouse.
- **HTML should probably be taking advantage of HTML5 semantics**
- This is less important, but I would still show the "Home" link.
- Update: Also, [use the proper heading level](https://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/Use_h1_for_Title) (h2 is not the top level)

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';

  var headerEl = document.querySelector('body > header');
  var btnEl = document.querySelector('.menu-btn');

  if(btnEl && headerEl) {
    btnEl.addEventListener('click', function() {
      headerEl.classList.toggle('open');
    });
  }
})();
```

```css
.page-header {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.page-header a { display: block; }

.page-header a,
.menu-btn {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  padding: 14px 16px;
}

button.menu-btn {
  border: none;
  background: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.page-header a:hover,
.page-header a:focus,
.menu-btn:hover,
.menu-btn:focus {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
  outline: none;
} 

.page-header:not(.open) a { display:none; }
.menu-btn { float: right; }

@media(min-width: 768px) {
  .page-header.page-header a { display: inline-block; }
  .menu-btn { display: none; }
}
```

```html
<header class="page-header">
  <button class="menu-btn">&#9776;</button>
  <nav>
    <a href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
  </nav>
</header>

<main>
  <h1>Responsive Topnav Example</h1>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see how it works.</p>
</main>
```

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is that you are hiding the elements when you go to the small state, but not showing them when you add the `.responsive` class. I have made some updates for you here:

https://jsfiddle.net/9xxzsypu/

```
.topnav.responsive li.item:not(:first-child) { display: block!important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your first media query:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .topnav li:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) {
         display: none;
    }
}
```

You basically set every list item in .topnav to display: none except for the first one. This made the hamburger menu invisible too.